# Printing and Reading Floating Point in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am brand new to the site and also very new to programming (as well as assembly). I am currently working on a simple program that calculates the area of a circle. I am certain that my program could be improved, but I still have a limited amount of knowledge in the subject and am trying to learn more. I am using QtSpim.

The issue that I am having is that every time I put any number (float) into the radius, the result always ends up being '**0.00000000**'. The idea is to capture a user's input, for example 3.0, then double it for the diameter, then ultimately multiply it by a simplified float of **pi** to reach the area of the circle.

**What I have noticed is if I hard code a radius, such as 3.0**, that it will display an area instead of the result of zeroes mentioned earlier.

Here is my code below:

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Please enter the radius of the circle. "
area: .asciiz "\n The area of the circle is: "
pi: .float 3.14
radius: .float 0.0
diameterL: .float 2.0

.text

.globl main

main:

# Intializing radius
lwc1 $f2, radius

# Intializing pi
lwc1 $f4, pi

# Intializing diameterL
lwc1 $f6, diameterL

# Display the message
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

# Read the input of the radius
li $v0, 6
mov.s $f2, $f2
syscall

# Calculating the diameter
mul.s $f10, $f6, $f2

# Display the area
li $v0, 2
mul.s $f12, $f10, $f4
syscall

# Terminate the program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Thanks for all your help/feedback!

Comment: It's unclear what you need the `mov.s $f2, $f2` for. In any case, the `read_float` puts the result into `$f0`.

Comment: I understand. I removed the line and changed the $f2 in the Diameter section, changed it to $f0 and it works! Thanks so much!